Exclude Spring 6 autoconfigure in Gradle
I have this Spring 5 configuration that I want to migrate to Spring Security 6:
implementation ('com.security.config:security:0.0.1') {
   exclude module: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure'
}

For Spring Security 6 I tried this:
implementation ('com.security.config:security:0.0.1') {
   exclude module: 'spring-security-oauth2-jose'
}

But when I start the Spring Boot project I get error:
The bean 'filterChain', defined in class path resource [com/DefaultSecurityConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/WebSecurityConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Jar dependencies:
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.17.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'

Do you know how I can properly configure what dependencies should be excluded in order to prevent security configuration from dependency jar?
